# Comparing dates in MMYY format

Tags: java, date-formatting

So I am making a Java program that processes a user's fake credit card and I am trying to make an expiration verification conditional statement. However, when I run my program, I get a "String cannot be converted to int" error. I would like to know how should I use the current month and year to check if the date entered by the user has actually expired.

```
do {
  System.out.print("Enter the expiration date mmyy: ");
  expiration = expnum.nextInt();

  DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy");
  Date date = new Date();
  System.out.println(dateformat.format(date));
  int currentdate = dateformat.format(date);

  if (currentdate <= expiration) {
    check = check + 1;
  } else {
    check = 1;
  }
} while (check == 1);
```

Comment: "processes a fake user's credit card" ... sketchy :)

Comment: `dateformat.format(date)` returns a `String`, you just need to convert that to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @ManoDestra's solution will work, I would prefer to keep the types/data sensible.  Thus, rather than convert the existing date into a `int` (which is kind of nonsensical, and the `format` followed by `parse` feels nasty), I would prefer to parse the expiration into a date and then compare directly.  Something like this:

```
expiration = expnum.nextInt();
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy");
Date expiryDate = dateFormat.parse(expiration);

Date currentDate = new Date();

if (currentDate.isAfter(expiryDate)) {
   // card has expired
} else {
   // card is still active
}
```

You'll probably need to tweak this depending on when you think the expiry actually happens.  If the expiry is specified as "0816" is that `01-Aug-2016 00:00:00.000`, or `31-Aug-2016 23:59:59.999`, or some point in between?

It's a call you have to make (probably by looking at the credit card spec), but that's another thing this approach has compared to the int-converting one: it's not just an abstract sense of "using proper types", but it translates to the real world too.  By converting the expiration string to a `Date`, you need to think about *exactly* what instant in time that represents, and exactly which values of "now" should count as expired and which should not.

Comment: He can still use ints to compared a year/month combo, but it would need to be formatted with year first, rather than last to enable int comparison of year/month in a credit card format. I updated my answer to reflect the problems with his current approach :)

Answer (score 2):

## `YearMonth` class

The [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents, well, a year and a month.

## java.time

This class is part of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as java.util.Date. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Parsing a String

Use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse your input string. When the century is omitted the 21st century `20` is assumed.

```
String input = "0616";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MMyy" );
YearMonth expiration = YearMonth.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "yearMonth = " + yearMonth );
```

> yearMonth = 2016-06

## Time Zone

Compare to the current `YearMonth`. Determining the current year-month means getting the current date. And determining the current date requires a time zone. The Question and other Answers ignore this crucial issue. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone. A few minutes after Paris is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal.

If omitted as an optional argument, the JVM’s current default time zone is silently implicitly applied. The current default [can change at any time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-), even during runtime(!). Better to specify the expected/desired time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.now( zoneId );
```

If your business rules happen to use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as the time zone, pass the handy constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) as the time zone argument.

## Compare

Lastly, we compare using `isBefore`, [`isAfter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#isAfter-java.time.YearMonth-), or [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

```
Boolean expired = currentYearMonth.isAfter( expiration );
```

Rather than passing around strings or integers for the year and month, pass around these `YearMonth` objects. You get the benefits of type safety, guaranteed valid values, and more self-documenting code.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it as a String in the form `yyMM`, whose natural ordering is correct:

```
int expiration; // MMyy
String expirationStr = String.format("%02d%02d", expiration % 100, expiration / 100);
String now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM").format(new Date());
if (expirationStr.compareTo(now) < 0)
    // expired
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not an int. It's a string. This is wrong:

```
int currentdate = dateformat.format(date);
```

If you really WANT an int, then convert it to an int:

```
int currentdate = Integer.parseInt(dateformat.format(date));
```

However, it won't be a terribly sensible int. If you wish to make this a more sensible int for comparison, then you'd have to put the year first, THEN the month (format: yyMM, or yyyyMM). That way, it will be a consecutive numerical comparison that CAN be compared against other credit card dates. Or, you could simply convert it to a `Date` or `Calendar` instead and use date comparisons.

Also, you should make the variable, `check`, a Boolean value. You have no need for it to be an numeric value.

Comment: This isn't ideal; you'd want to compare dates as opposed to relying on integers.

Comment: This partly solved my problem but I would like to know how I can edit the expiration check so that certain values wouldn't work. For example, there are twelve months, though if I entered 13 as MM, the program would still return true.

Comment: Not ideal, but this is the solution to his given issue and chosen design.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace expnum.nextInt(); with Integer.parseInt(expnum.nextLine());  This will take the input string, and convert it to an int.  If they don't put an int though, it will through an exception, so you can put that inside a try-catch statement (and put that in like in a while loop or something so it keeps asking till they answer in the proper format if you want).