# How do I check if a string is in this format MM-YY in Java ?

Tags: java, sql, controls, string-formatting

I have to add into a Database a string in format "MM-YY" which represents expiration date from a Credit Card , where MM is the month and YY are the last two digits of the Year , how do I check if a String is in this this specific format in Java ?

Comment: have look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or

Comment: @rieckpil This Question is not an exact duplicate of [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or). That one was about year-month-day while this one is about year-month. Different solution, using [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class here.

Comment: Similar: [*Comparing dates in MMYY format*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38134680/642706)

Comment: @BasilBourque, I didn't mark this question as a duplicate. Is just posted a possible way to support finding the solution for himself ;)

Comment: thanks everyone , I resolved the Issue

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
String myString = "12-99";

if( myString.matches("((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-\\d{2}") ){
   System.out.println("Correct format");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Incorrect format");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below regex

```
String str = "10-18";
if (str.matches("([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})"))
 System.out.println("Correct");
else 
System.out.println("Incorrect");
```

Answer (score 0):

## `java.time.YearMonth`

Parse as a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). Trap for exception.

```
String input = "99-18" ;  // Valid: "01-18"  Invalid: "99-18"
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-uu" ) ;

YearMonth ym = null ;
try {
    ym = YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println( "Invalid input: " + input ) ;
}

System.out.println( "ym.toString(): " + ym ) ;
```

See this [code run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/9kIqvS).

> Invalid input: 99-18
>
> ym.toString(): null

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).